# What is the reason for xamarin app style change?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, colors, themes

I'm from Ukraine, so I immediately apologize for my crooked English. I got one very incomprehensible problem with which I can not figure it out. I have created a mobile application for Android and IOS. Absolutely normal application. I tested it on the emulator on several phones. But on one of them, the app didn't look like itself. For some reason it became dark and looked strange (I attached the screenshots). The normal version is white-green, this version was dark. I can't figure out what is the reason. Immediately I will say that the phone is normal and the light theme is enabled on it, the phone has standard settings. And everything else on this phone except this application is displayed normally. Please tell me what is the reason

I tried to change the themes and settings of the phone, and found out that the problem is definitely not in them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZitk.png)

Comment: Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. 
Dark mode is not supported before iOS 13 . Maybe on that one phone the version is different

Comment: What is the device that is experiencing this problem? And what is the phone model and system version?